# Why I kill openarena process fail?

Tags: 14.04

I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>,type `top`,`kill` `pid`,`killall ioquake3`.
Then I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>, `openarena` is freezing, I wanna kill it and return to unity.

Comment: what is openarena? If desktop simply log out and select unity at log in screen.

Comment: According to wikipedia,OpenArena is a free and open-source video game, it is first-person shooter (FPS) and a video game clone of Quake III Arena.I wanna kill openarena because it is in tty environment.

Comment: Did you do a `kill -9 PID`?

Comment: Let me post an answer then glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your situation a *solid* kill command with the kill signal (`9 or SIGKILL`) should help. So do the following passing in the process ID (PID):

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

This is usually guaranteed to do the job.